# Using `super()` when extending `Object`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a class that extends `Object` in JavaScript and expect `super()` to initialise the keys/values when constructing a new instance of this class.

```js
class ExtObject extends Object {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
  }
}

const obj = new Object({foo:'bar'});
console.log(obj); // { foo: 'bar' }

const ext = new ExtObject({foo:'bar'});
console.log(ext); // ExtObject {}

console.log(ext.foo); // undefined
```

Why isn't `foo` defined as `'bar'` on `ext` in this example?

**EDIT**

**Explanation**: [Using `super()` when extending `Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439332/using-super-when-extending-object#answer-51443624)

**Solution**: [Using `super()` when extending `Object`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439332/using-super-when-extending-object#answer-51439586)

Comment: Although I can't answer your question, I can't help but wonder why you would even want to `extend Object`.

Comment: Because I want the instances of the extended class to act the same as Object as well as have custom functionality.  I get your point, because I guess the same functionality can be created when not extending `Object` and using `Object.assign()` in the constructor, as Gildas.Tambo suggests. But it really makes me wonder why it's not working this way..

Comment: The funny thing about this issue is that Babel can transpile this code to give the correct results

Comment: Questions are questions. There are **no** reason why it should include a link to the answer. You can pin an answer to the top by accepting it, but that's it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nobody has actually explained why it doesn't work. If we look [at the latest spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-object-constructor), the `Object` function is defined as follows:

> **19.1.1.1 Object ( [ value ] )**
>
> When `Object` function is called with optional argument `value`, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If `NewTarget` is neither `undefined` nor the active function, then
>
>    1. Return ? `OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(NewTarget, "%ObjectPrototype%")`.
> 2. If `value` is `null`, `undefined` or not supplied, return `ObjectCreate(%ObjectPrototype%)`.
> 3. Return ! `ToObject(value)`.

The first step is the important one here:  `NewTarget` refers to the function that `new` was called upon. So if you do `new Object`, it will be `Object`. If you call `new ExtObject` it will `ExtObject`.

Because `ExtObject` is not `Object` (*"nor the active function"*), the condition matches and `OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor` is evaluated and its result returned. As you can see, nothing is done with the `value` passed to the function.

`value` is only used if neither 1. nor 2. are fulfilled. And if `value` is an object, it is simply returned as is, no new object is created. So, `new Object(objectValue)` is actually the same as `Object(objectValue)`:

```js
var foo = {bar: 42};
console.log(new Object(foo) === foo);
console.log(Object(foo) === foo);
```

In other words: `Object` does not copy the properties of the passed in object, it simply returns the object as is. So extending `Object` wouldn't copy the properties either.

Comment: Great, finally understand why using `Object.create()` can only do the same job as `Object` but cannot add an extend method.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
class ExtObject extends Object {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    Object.assign(this, ...args);
  }
}

const obj = new Object({foo:'bar'});
console.log(obj); // { foo: 'bar' }

const ext = new ExtObject({foo:'bar'});
console.log(ext); // { foo: 'bar' }

console.log(ext.foo); // bar
```

Comment: Although this works, we wouldn't be needing the `extends Object` and  `super()` in this case, right? I guess this is more like 'copying' the source of the parents (Object) constructor method?

Comment: Yes , since we are working with objects try to understand ECMAScript 6 Class and Inheritance and Super class calls with super  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: @TimBaas I am doubt with this ans.... Let say you remove `extends Object` and `super(...args)` , everything work well... it is just copying the value.

Answer (score 5):

This answer works only when using the Babel transpiler.

Because Object's constructor **returns** value. See [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.2.1)

> 15.2.2.1 new Object ( [ value ] ) 
>   When the Object constructor is called with no arguments or with one argument value, the following steps are taken: 
>   ... 
>   8. **Returns obj.**

```js
class ExtObject extends Object {
  constructor(...args) {
    return super(...args);
  }
}

const obj = new Object({foo:'bar'});
console.log(obj); // { foo: 'bar' }

const ext = new ExtObject({foo:'bar'});
console.log(ext); // { foo: 'bar' }

console.log(ext.foo); // bar
```

Comment: @barbsan this is not a valid answer, you are using babel to transpile the code, that is why it worked , in browsers which supports ES6 natively , this will not work

Comment: @Caramiriel That's because you're returning a new Object: `{foo:'bar'}` in the constructor. In barbsan's answer `super()` is returned which is not a new object but a new instance of this class.

Comment: @Caramiriel because I selected Babel transpiler in snippet's settings